# UseSWR returning undefined data even when fetcher function returns

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

When trying to get UseSWR to properly return from a JSON API, I copied and pasted the sample code from their website and switched around the API, but any attempt to access the values in `data` or `error`, such as `console.log('Data from top level: ' + data)` returns only `undefined`.

```
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', fetcher)
```

Appending `.then(json => console.log(json))` to the end of the fetcher function logs the correct value. After searching StackOverflow and finding many answers talking about the fetcher function needing to return its value, I tried this, but `const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json()).then((json) => { return json; })` and variations did not solve the issue.

I've attempted the following `useEffect()` implementation, but run into the same problem:

```
  const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json));
  const { data, error } = useSWR('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', fetcher)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`From error:  ${error}`)
    console.log(`Data from top level: ${data}`)
  }, [data, error]
  )
```

My dependencies are here:

```
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "swr": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to await the data by including the isLoading prop returned from useSWR:

```js
const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json));
const { data, isLoading, error } = useSWR('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', fetcher)

if (isLoading) {
  return <div>Loading data...</div>
}
```

Comment: Hi! I think you're right about the problem, but I don't think I fully understand your solution. Updated post to include my attempted implementation of `useEffect()`

Comment: Just edited my post. I realized, I run into the same problem when I remove `isLoading` and early return statement from my own code. So solution is to handle handle variables that are undefined while waiting for the data. Let me know if my updated solution works for you :-)

Comment: Use can also do this without `isLoading`, but then you have to use useEffect to make sure that undefined values are not used in the render method. You can check a working example here: https://github.com/MadsAkselsen/discover-coffee-stores/blob/617fb2a981d6b875b5c06db3e0c30e22b7244899/pages/coffee-store/%5Bid%5D.js#L7